# Why HTTP/2 Multiplexing is better than http/1.1?

Tags: http, http2

In HTTP/1.1 Case, a web page has multiple resouces, per file will create a connection to server side to retrieve data, js, css, etc. I think the mode of work **is similar to mutli-process or multi-thread, work in parallel**.

But in HTTP/2 Case, per domain only has one connection in a web page, even if it can handle mutliple request from client's browser, maybe it **is similar to single thread**.

I don't know the reason why the performance is better in http/2 than in http/1.1 ?

Comment: A bus is better than 30 cars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason HTTP/2 multiplexing is more efficient than HTTP/1.1 for web pages has very little to do with the cost of opening TCP connections.

In HTTP/1.1, browsers open typically at most 6 connections per domain.
After those connections are open, they are kept open and reused over and over, until they go idle.

Yet, HTTP/2 is faster than HTTP/1.1 even *after* those connections have been opened, so it is clearly not the cost of TCP connection opening in play here.

A typical web page today may have up to 100 resources to be downloaded from the origin server.
Let's keep things simple and imagine there is a 200 ms roundtrip between client and server. In order to download the page in HTTP/1.1, the browser has to download the main HTML page (1 roundtrip), then parse the HTML page and arrange to download the 100 resources - but it only has 6 connections.
So the browser sends the first 6 requests, then waits for them to come back (1 roundtrip); then another 6 requests, then waits for them to come back (1 roundtrip); etc.
In this simple model, to download 100 resources the browser needs 1 + 17 roundtrips, at 200 ms each it means 3.6 seconds.

In HTTP/2, the browser makes the request for the HTML page, but then it is free to make all the requests for the 100 resources *without waiting*, thanks to the fact that HTTP/2 is multiplexed.
In this simple model, to download 100 resources the browser needs 1 + 1 roundtrips, that is 400 ms, for a 10x speedup in download time.

Now, things are not as simple as depicted above, but still the gain due to multiplexing has quite an impact.

You can look at this impact yourself by watching examples online ([here](https://http2.golang.org/gophertiles) and [here](https://http2.akamai.com/demo)), and you can watch [my HTTP/2 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLtBftqM04) on this and other HTTP/2 benefits (you can watch the demo that explains the multiplexing effect [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLtBftqM04&t=2208)).

Comment: True, though I'll add that a hypothetical browser opening a tcp connection per resource in http/1.1 would incur some over head and latency compared to a single TCP connection with a stream per resource in http/2.  Basically, for the same reason - roundtrip time, since a TCP connection per resource would add an additional roundtrip per resource for the handshake.  So, in another hypothetical example of a normal browser and a page with just 6 resources to download, the difference is going to be purely in the TCP setup costs and in total, very small.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a TCP connection is a costly operation, it's similar to copying one big file and thousands of small ones, or moving a big box and lots of small ones

Comment: You have to complete a handshake each time you open a connection, that's one of reasons of it's high cost.

Comment: Can multi-core CPU work in multi-thread mode can't handle it? I think if it can not perform handshake at the same time?

Comment: @scott1028 it's more about your network connection, even if your CPU can do something simultaneously, you have to receive the data over your network, which is somewhat critical section. You >have< to do lots of handshakes over your network, and with http2 you have to do it only once

Comment: @scott1028 and of course if you have more than one connection available you can get use of it, but it's not an everyday story